# Get only a particular attribute Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, attributes

I want to get only like count and not like data, can it be done using fields=like_count or something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `fields` to get only those properties. check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=1274834235%3Ffields%3Dname), some fields are fixed for some objects.

If you use fql, use . operator eg:

> user.email

Comment: This is on the homepage of the Graph API documentation, i'm surprised the OP managed to miss it

Comment: @lgy Yeah I should have considered it before anwsering.

Comment: I can get like_count+like_data using fields=likes but I want only the count to speed up loading times.